# Coded UI Test find instance 1 and 2 of a button but fails to find instance 3, 4 or 5

Tags: c#, instance, coded-ui-tests

I am testing a tabbed control that has 5 tabs. Each tab is opened by button so there are 5 wpf buttons. I recorded a test method to open each of these tabs and it opened tab 1 every time. That makes some sense so I made 5 copies of the method (using "Move code to UIMap.cs" option) and put in the Instance search property to search for instances 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. This works for instances 1 and 2 but does not work for instance 3 onwards.

My question is what do I need to do to click instance 3, 4 and 5 of the button that I can already click instance 1 and 2 of?

My Test method (works well for tabs 1 and 2 but stops at tab 3):

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Common_CompleteTestData_TabbedForm()
    {
        this.UIMap.Configuration_Tab1_Click();
        //Do stuff in tab 1.
        this.UIMap.Configuration_Tab2_Click();
        //Do stuff in tab 2.
        this.UIMap.Configuration_Tab3_Click();
        //Do stuff in tab 3.
        this.UIMap.Configuration_Tab4_Click();
        //Do stuff in tab 4.
        this.UIMap.Configuration_Tab5_Click();
        //Do stuff in tab 5.
    }
```

UIMap.cs:

```
public void Configuration_Tab1_Click()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfRadioButton uIUCRadioButton = this.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientShWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientInCustom2.UIUCRadioButton;
        uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.Instance] = "1";
        #endregion

        // Select 'UC' radio button
        uIUCRadioButton.Selected = this.Configuration_Tab_n_ClickParams.UIUCRadioButtonSelected;
    }

    public void Configuration_Tab2_Click()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfRadioButton uIUCRadioButton = this.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientShWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientInCustom2.UIUCRadioButton;
        uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.Instance] = "2";
        #endregion

        // Select 'UC' radio button
        uIUCRadioButton.Selected = this.Configuration_Tab_n_ClickParams.UIUCRadioButtonSelected;
    }

    public void Configuration_Tab3_Click()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfRadioButton uIUCRadioButton = this.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientShWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientInCustom2.UIUCRadioButton;
        uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.Instance] = "3";
        #endregion

        // Select 'UC' radio button
        uIUCRadioButton.Selected = this.Configuration_Tab_n_ClickParams.UIUCRadioButtonSelected;
    }

    public void Configuration_Tab4_Click()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfRadioButton uIUCRadioButton = this.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientShWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientInCustom2.UIUCRadioButton;
        uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.Instance] = "4";
        #endregion

        // Select 'UC' radio button
        uIUCRadioButton.Selected = this.Configuration_Tab_n_ClickParams.UIUCRadioButtonSelected;
    }

    public void Configuration_Tab5_Click()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfRadioButton uIUCRadioButton = this.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientShWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientInCustom2.UIUCRadioButton;
        uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.Instance] = "5";
        #endregion

        // Select 'UC' radio button
        uIUCRadioButton.Selected = this.Configuration_Tab_n_ClickParams.UIUCRadioButtonSelected;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Rescis's idea to create a list of controls using FindMatchingControls and then selecting the instance.

```
    public void Configuration_Tab_n_Click_New(int instance)
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfRadioButton uIUCRadioButton = this.UIOptimalSynTQClientShWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIOptimalSynTQClientInCustom2.UIUCRadioButton;
        uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties.Add(WpfRadioButton.PropertyNames.ControlType, "RadioButton");
        uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties.Add(WpfRadioButton.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.RadioButton");
        #endregion

        var uIUCRadioButtonList = uIUCRadioButton.FindMatchingControls();
        var clickableButton = uIUCRadioButtonList[instance];
        var point = clickableButton.BoundingRectangle;
        Point relativePoint = new Point(point.X + 10, point.Y + 10);
        Mouse.Click(clickableButton, relativePoint);
    }

    //Run the test
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Common_Configuration_SelectTab_3_New()
    {
        this.UIMap.Configuration_Tab_n_Click_New(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this (with each respective number):

```
WpfRadioButton uIUCRadioButton = this.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientShWindow.UIDesignSurfaceCustom.UIWPFDTAppSynTQClientInCustom2.UIUCRadioButton;
// May not be neccesarry, I'm not sure how this is implemented.
uIUCRadioButton.SearchProperties.Add(WpfControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Button");

// Select 'UC' radio button by finding the control at index number
uIUCRadioButton = uIUCRadioButton.FindMatchingControls()[ControlNumber]
//Here, deal with the click logic.  Again, not sure on implementation
uIUCRadioButton.Selected = this.Configuration_Tab_n_ClickParams.UIUCRadioButtonSelected;
```

Comment: Rescis, you put me on the right track but I found syntax errors in your code so I ultimately didn't manage to implement your solution exactly. I did use your idea to FindMatchingControls though so thank you very much.

Comment: Sure thing.  Its been a while since I dealt with the UI map, so I'll take fault for the errors.  Mind telling me what they were so I can update the answer?

Comment: I was unable to use FindMatchingControls in the way you used it. I had to split it out across 2 lines of code. I then wanted to click the button so I used an approach I have used before. Your approach looks cleaner but doesn't click. I should probably investigate your way of selecting and then click that but that's a different question.